# the files with their name having space are not getting compiled

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, compilation

Compiling my c++ program with vscode. the files with their name having space are not getting compiled

````
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "shell: g++.exe build active file",
            "command":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": ["-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe", "-std=c++11"],
            "options": {
                "cwd":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}```
````

Comment: Easiest solution is not to have files whose names include spaces.

Comment: use `"\"${file}\""` and also quote the .exe, much better as Sam said: **Never use spaces in filenames**

Answer (score 1):

That's the way it is. Chekcout the command VSCode uses to compile and run and c++ file:

```
cd "c:\Users\Deep Raval\Desktop\" ; if ($?) { g++ -std=c++14 garbage 2.cpp -o garbage 2 } ; if ($?) { .\garbage 2 }
```

More specifically spaced file creates confusion of weather it is command or actual file name.

To resolve you can use `_` instead of `space`.

Or you can design your custom command depending upon your OS.